# How can I write a script that opens a notification?

Tags: macos, applescript, notifications, script

Is there an apple script that can click on the notification for me so that I don't have to open the app using a mouse?

I plan to bind this script to a keyboard shortcut and that way I can open incoming notifications with just the keyboard.

Here are two notifications type examples

[image]

[image]

Note that scripts like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300317/applescript-how-to-close-notification-alerts-from-a-specific-application/300323?r=SearchResults&s=8%7C0.0000#300323) wont work because it attempts to click on a button and there's no consistent button to click on to open a notification. Sometimes its top, sometimes its bottom, sometimes its neither.

What is needed is a script that clicks on the "left" part of the notification, that will always open the app.

Comment: Added the details

Answer (score 1):

Testing under **macOS High Sierra**, the following line of *example* **AppleScript** *code*, when run, had the following general effects on a **notification**:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click every window of application process "Notification Center"
```

- Open the app for which the notification was from, if it wasn't already opened.
- If the app was already open, it would set focus to the app.
- If notification from multiple apps, the app on the top notification in the list gets opened/focus, additions apps get opened, if not already open.

Note that with some notifications, they will be dismissed; however, with others, the app will still be opened/focused as applicable but the notification will not be dismissed. These will need to be replied to appropriately.

Comment: Looks like this is now broken in big sur, and instead open the notifciations center. Any solution?